# listings package : highlight word composed by an alphabetic and a numeric part

Tags: listings

I would like to highlight several keywords with an alphabetic and a numeric part with different color.

My problem is the number of keywords can become huge from r0 to r191 for example.
And I have several keywords.
Is there a way to escape to write all the possible keywords ?

Is there a way to define left delimiter just for a word and not for a line ?

The sample bellow do exactly what I want but with writing all the keywords (example keywords[2] and keywords[3])...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.4,0.0}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0.0,0.0}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{mylanguage}
                  {keywords=[1]{add,sub,test},
                    keywords=[2]{r0,r1,r2},
                    keywords=[3]{p00,p01,p10,p11},
                    moredelim=[s][\footnotesize\textit]{<}{>},
                    keywordstyle=[1]\normalsize\color{gray}\bfseries\ttfamily,
                    keywordstyle=[2]\color{darkgreen},
                    keywordstyle=[3]\color{darkred}}

\begin{document}

\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt,language=mylanguage}
\begin{lstlisting}
  p00 add r0 , r1 , r2
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436) ... are you writing assembler?

Comment: yes, it is my assembler language

Comment: `listings` supports assembler, although only specific dialects.  It would be useful to see how they define it for themselves; the structure is pretty consistent.  I'm going to research where it defines the languages (`grep` to the rescue!), but two heads are better than one, no?

Comment: It looks like the answer won't come that easy.  A quick look at `listing`'s [source code](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx) (search "Assembler") reveals that they do it the dumb way, too.  There is probably a way to script this, but it won't use the `listings` package itself.  Your best bet is some sort of text generating command, perhaps (depending on how `\lstdefinelanguage` works).

Comment: ok thanks, i will generate all my alphanumeric keywords ... a little "brute force" but ok

Comment: I was thinking more of a LaTeX way to do it - have it do the heavy lifting so you don't have to look at it XD  I'll get back to you once I have a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Huge* hat tip to David, first of all, for providing a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100041/17423) to a tricky intermediate problem.  I couldn't have done this without his help.

You can do this quite easily by simply generating the list with LaTeX itself (it is Turing-complete, after all, hehe).  Notice that this requires the `forloop` package (a really simple macro, actually).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{color,forloop}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.4,0.0}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0.0,0.0}

\newcounter{ct}
\makeatletter
% Since we don't want an initial comma in the list, we use \@gobble
\def\rlist{\@gobble}
%  Using the counter ct, range its value from 0 to 191
\forloop{ct}{0}{\value{ct} < 192}{%
    % \edef expands the definition before it actually 
    % binds the two.  Thus, \rlist expands like a chameleon's tongue.
    \edef\rlist{\rlist,r\arabic{ct}}
  }

\makeatother
\def\listwithrs#1\relax{%
\lstdefinelanguage{mylanguage}
                  {keywords=[1]{add,sub,test},
                   keywords=[2]{#1},  % we stick in the list here
                   keywords=[3]{p00,p01,p10,p11},
                   moredelim=[s][\footnotesize\textit]{<}{>},
                   keywordstyle=[1]\normalsize\color{gray}\bfseries\ttfamily,
                   keywordstyle=[2]\color{red},
                   keywordstyle=[3]\color{darkred}}}

\usepackage{listings}

% Since we want to know the value of \rlist before we define the language,
% we use \expandafter to 'skip' \listwithrs so \rlist can be evaluated.
\expandafter\listwithrs\rlist\relax

\begin{document}

\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt,language=mylanguage}
\begin{lstlisting}
  p00 add r0 , r1 , r2 , r3 , r4
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks!! How can I pass a second list argument to `\listwithrs` ? I tried `\def\listwithrs#1#2...` and `\expandafter\listwithrs\rlist\plist\relax` but unsuccessful

Comment: I tried the same thing at first.  I'll have to direct you to David's solution again (linked above) for that answer.  Be sure to upvote it!!