# Forcing macro expansion with keyval

Tags: macros, expansion, key-value

While trying to provide an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100019), I've run into a stumbling block that I can't seem to get over.  The `listings` package (like many others) uses `keyval` to handle configuration.  What should be done if part of that configuration is a macro that must be expanded prior?

All (admittedly semirandom) configurations of `\expandafter` produce some sort of error or another.  The closest I got was getting an error that complained about the fact that TeX was encountering text (keys) before `\begin{document}`.

Is there any way to get around this?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{color,forloop}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.4,0.0}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0.0,0.0}

\newcounter{ct}
\newcommand{\lstkeygenr}{%
  \forloop{ct}{0}{\value{ct} < 50}{%
    r\arabic{ct},
  }
}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{mylanguage}
                  {keywords=[1]{add,sub,test},
                   keywords=[2]{r0,r1,r2,\lstkeygenr},
                   keywords=[3]{p00,p01,p10,p11},
                   moredelim=[s][\footnotesize\textit]{<}{>},
                   keywordstyle=[1]\normalsize\color{gray}\bfseries\ttfamily,
                   keywordstyle=[2]\color{red},
                   keywordstyle=[3]\color{darkred}}

\begin{document}

\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt,language=mylanguage}
\begin{lstlisting}
  p00 add r0 , r1 , r2 , r3 , r4
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to pass a macro with a loop in as the key value, you want to pass in a list generated by such a loop, so you need to invert your calling order:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{color,forloop}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.4,0.0}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0.0,0.0}

\newcounter{ct}
\makeatletter
\def\rlist{\@gobble}
\forloop{ct}{0}{\value{ct} < 50}{%
    \edef\rlist{\rlist,r\arabic{ct}}
  }

\makeatother
\def\listwithrs#1\relax{%
\lstdefinelanguage{mylanguage}
                  {keywords=[1]{add,sub,test},
                   keywords=[2]{#1},
                   keywords=[3]{p00,p01,p10,p11},
                   moredelim=[s][\footnotesize\textit]{<}{>},
                   keywordstyle=[1]\normalsize\color{gray}\bfseries\ttfamily,
                   keywordstyle=[2]\color{red},
                   keywordstyle=[3]\color{darkred}}}

\usepackage{listings}
\expandafter\listwithrs\rlist\relax

\begin{document}

\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt,language=mylanguage}
\begin{lstlisting}
  p00 add r0 , r1 , r2 , r3 , r4
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

---

as requested a versuion defining xlist instead of rlist that takes a macro defining the prefix letter (so `\xlist r` is same as the original `\rlist`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{color,forloop}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.0,0.4,0.0}
\definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.6,0.0,0.0}

\newcounter{ct}
\makeatletter
\def\xxlist{\@gobble}
\let\xhash\relax
\forloop{ct}{0}{\value{ct} < 50}{%
    \edef\xxlist{\xxlist,\xhash1\arabic{ct}}
  }
\let\xhash#
\expandafter\def\expandafter\xlist\expandafter#\expandafter1\expandafter{\xxlist}

\typeout{^^J\string\xlist^^J\meaning\xlist}

\makeatother
\def\listwithrs#1\relax{%
\lstdefinelanguage{mylanguage}
                  {keywords=[1]{add,sub,test},
                   keywords=[2]{#1},
                   keywords=[3]{p00,p01,p10,p11},
                   moredelim=[s][\footnotesize\textit]{<}{>},
                   keywordstyle=[1]\normalsize\color{gray}\bfseries\ttfamily,
                   keywordstyle=[2]\color{red},
                   keywordstyle=[3]\color{darkred}}}

\usepackage{listings}

\expandafter\listwithrs\xlist r\relax

\begin{document}

\lstset{numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=1, numbersep=5pt,language=mylanguage}
\begin{lstlisting}
  p00 add r0 , r1 , r2 , r3 , r4
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's that `\@gobble` business?

Comment: @vermiculus \@gobble is defined in latex by \def\@gobble#1{} so it throws away its argument, in this case the argument is the `,` before the first real item, saves testing for the first one and not putting the comma in.

Comment: Is there any way to make this solution (namely `\rlist`) take an a prefix argument (r1, r2 ... r50 vs. p01,p02,...p50), or would it make things drastically more complicated?  Just curious; I don't *think* the original asker needs that.

Comment: @vermiculus answer updated

Comment: I'll have to remember `\typeout`.  Also, *this is so cool!*  Thanks for updating!